# Retrieving Anonymous Object's Property in C#

Tags: c#, anonymous

I have the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        list.Add(new {
            Value = 0
        });
        //Console.WriteLine(list[0].Value);
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way to write the commented line of code without causing a compile time error? I know I could resort to using the dynamic keyword or implementing an extension method for the Object class that uses Reflection, but is there maybe another more acceptable way?

The goal is the avoid creating a class since its only purpose would be to store data. But at the same time still be able to retrieve the data later on in the program. This code will eventually end up in a web method which is why I want it to be dynamic / anonymous in the first place. All of the objects would end up having the same properties, as they would be storing values stored in tables, but the values are needed later for other calculations.

Comment: Why use `List<object>` and anonymous object in the first place? Surely you have some idea about what items you're going to store in the list?

Comment: I fear that the `dynamic` keyword is the only usable solution.

Comment: The only 2 ways to do it are using dynamic or reflection.

Comment: Sounds like the more important question here is *why*? Why not share what you are actually trying to achieve here (with real examples instead of contrived ones) as there is probably a better way.

Comment: `object` doesn't have a `Value` property so, no.  Instead of trying to make the compiler think that it does, approach this from another angle.  `object` is the wrong abstraction.  If any given element in the collection should have a `Value` property then the collection should be statically typed to a type with a `Value` property (interface, base class, etc.).  Alternatively, `dynamic`.

Comment: Do you really need a `List<object>`, meaning will your list contain multiple types, or just this one anonymous type?

Comment: @antp i added my end goal to the question, i hope that answers why i want to do this

Comment: @LoganMurphy What you're describing is a DTO. Just write a class. Trying to use anonymous objects for this is going to lead you into a mess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to write the commented line of code without causing a compile time error?

Not with the way you've declared the list.  If your list will contain only objects of that anonymous type, you could use an array initializer and convert it to a `List<{anonymous type}>`:

```
var list = (new [] {
         new { Value = 0 }
     }).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(list[0].Value);
```

The nice thing is that you can *add* to the list easily, since anonymous types with the same properties are merged into one type by the compiler:

```
list.Add(new {Value = 1});
```

Per Servy's comment, a method to avoid an array creation would just be:

```
public static List<T> CreateList<T>(params T[] items)
{
     return new List<T>(items);
}
```

usage:

```
var list = CreateList(new { Value = 0 });
```

Comment: I was trying to think of a way to do it via an initialiser, i din't think of the array then `ToList()` method.

Comment: You can write your own generic method to avoid the array creation as well.

Comment: @servy i would like to see an example of a method that can generate this array and how you would call it

Comment: @LoganMurphy The whole point of the method is to *not* generate an array, and it's as simple as a generic method that accepts one or more items typed as the generic argument and adds them to a new list.  There's nothing else to it.